# jQuery jqGrid - Accessing data after changing grid type to 'local' from 'xml'

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am having two issues with `jqGrid` with which I hope somebody can help.

The scenario is that I have a `jqGrid` that is initially loaded via XML and after loading, the grid is set to be a local grid (via `$('#mygrid').setGridParam({datatype: 'local'}).trigger('reloadGrid')` in `document.ready()`. I did it in `document.ready` because it didn't work in `loadComplete` or `gridComplete`).

The data for the grid loads correctly and the grid datatype is set to local, but if I try to sort for example, the grid rows disappear. Similarly, if  I try an access the grid data programmatically (using `$('#mygrid').getGridParam('data')` or `$('#mygrid')[0].p.data)`, I cannot - it is empty/not available.

Am I missing a step here? Am I supposed to be manually doing something to copy the initially loaded data into the local space? I thought of getting the data from the grid before setting it to local, looping through and manually adding rows using `addRowData()`, but 1) I'm not sure how to get data from non-local grid and 2) it seems like extraordinary effort and I'm missing something.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this functionality? Why load that data via XML and then swap to local? If that is truly necessary you might as well populate a local array and then feed that to the grid so it is always a local source but I would be curious what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

you tried to run the [example](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#t5) such as this in the demos without loading the xml only with test data.

if everything works add the xml.

Comment: I ended up spitting the data out onto the page as a javascript array and setting  the jqGrid to local right from the start. I thought there was another way to do it that I was missing, but this works fine. Thanks for leading me in right direction. I apparently can't accept answers though...